# How to change columns in a datable based on a specific line of data

Tags: r, datatable, data-manipulation, calculated-columns

I have bilateral exchanges data, such as :

```
library(datatable)

mwe <- data.table(Importer=c("Country_A","Country_A","Country_A","Country_A",
                             "Country_B","Country_B","Country_B","Country_B",
                             "World","World","World","World",
                             "Country_C","Country_C","Country_C","Country_C"),
                  Short_Importer=c("A","A","A","A",
                                   "B","B","B","B",
                                   "W","W","W","W",
                                   "C","C","C","C"),
                  Exporter=c("Country_A", "Country_B", "World", "Country_C",
                             "Country_A", "Country_B", "World", "Country_C",
                             "Country_A", "Country_B", "World", "Country_C",
                             "Country_A", "Country_B", "World", "Country_C"),
                  Value=c(0,12,36,24,
                          10,0,44,34,
                          30,22,110,58,
                          20,10,30,0))
```

I have changed it in a wider format

```
mwe_wide <- dcast(mwe, Importer + Short_Importer ~ Exporter, value.var = "Value")
```

I would like this datable, but with shares in columns instead of values. 
I would therefore like to simply replace columns 3 to 5 by the same values divided by the amount on the same column for the line world. I assume it is not very complicated but have not found a satisfying way to do it. 
I have in reality several subregions, so I would like to avoid deleting the line world and then divising by the sum.

```
desired_output <- data.table(Importer=c("Country_A", "Country_B", "Country_C", "World"),
                             Short_Importer=c("A","B","C","W"),
                             Country_A =c(0,0.33,0.66,1),
                             Country_B =c(0,0.55,0.45,1),
                             Country_C =c(0,0.41,0.59,1),
                             World =c(0.33,0.40,0.27,1))
```

Comment: I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to divide by the last row where the 'Importer' is 'World'

```
mwe_wide[, (3:6) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
           round(x/x[Importer == "World"],  2)), .SDcols = 3:6] 
mwe_wide
#    Importer Short_Importer Country_A Country_B Country_C World
#1: Country_A              A      0.00      0.55      0.41  0.33
#2: Country_B              B      0.33      0.00      0.59  0.40
#3: Country_C              C      0.67      0.45      0.00  0.27
#4:     World              W      1.00      1.00      1.00  1.00
```

Or with `Map`

```
mwe_wide[, (3:6) := Map(`/`, .SD, .SD[Importer == 'World']), .SDcols = 3:6]
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. As it happens too often, I have not thought through my mwe... I actually have two columns of literate informations (a country, and an abbreviation of the country name) and I would like to keep both. How can I specifiy that I would like the value of the second columns to be my reference, somthink like  : `mwe_wide[, (3:5) := .SD/Column2.Value=("World"), .SDcols = 3:5]. I will update my mwe if this comment is unclear
`

Comment: You can use `get`

Comment: Actually, I was not clear, I would like the world total used to divide to be the one in the last line, not the last column

Comment: @AnthonyMartin  Do you need `mwe_wide[, (2:4) := lapply(.SD, `/`, World[.N]), .SDcols = 2:4]

Comment: I think the second version is exactly what I needed, Thanks for your patience. If it does not take too much time to sligthly explain the code you used it might be a bit more helpful to adapt it. I will check tomorrow the `map` instructions on my own, but the use of `round(x/x` in the first solution puzzles me for now

Comment: @AnthonyMartin in the first case we loop over the columns 3 to 6 with `lapply`, then dividie those columns by the value where the 'Importer' is 'World' (assuming there  is only one), and `round`the output of the division  to two digits.  then we assign the output to those columns